# Cannot make non-abstract subclass of abstract superclass?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, compiler-errors, abstract

I have a subclass that declares all of the methods in my abstract superclass, yet it still gives me an error stating that my class isn't abstract. I cannot figure out why this error is getting thrown.

The specific error I'm getting is

> PhoneBookEntry.java:1: error: PhoneBookEntry is not abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo(Object) in Comparable

My code in question:

```
public abstract class PhoneNumber implements Comparable
{
   protected String firstName, lastName;
   protected int number;

   public PhoneNumber(String firstName, String lastName, int number)
   {
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
      this.number = number;
   }

   public abstract String getLastName();
   public abstract String getFirstName();
   public abstract int getNumber();

   public int compareTo(PhoneNumber other)
   {
      int last = other.lastName.compareTo(lastName);
      int first = other.firstName.compareTo(firstName);
      int num = other.number - number;
      if(last > 0)
         return 1;
      else if(last < 0)
         return -1;
      else
         if(first > 0)
            return 1;
         else if(first < 0)
            return -1;
         else
            if(num > 0)
               return 1;
            else if(num < 0)
               return -1;
            else 
               return 0;
   }
}
```

And my subclass:

```
public class PhoneBookEntry extends PhoneNumber
{
   public PhoneBookEntry(String firstName, String lastName, int number)
   {
      super(firstName, lastName, number);
   }

    public String getLastName()
   {
      return lastName;
   }
   public String getFirstName()
   {
      return firstName;
   }
   public int getNumber()
   {
      return number;
   }

   public int compareTo(PhoneNumber other)
   {
      super.compareTo(other);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

This is the problem:

```
public int compareTo(PhoneNumber other)
{
   super.compareTo(other);
}
```

You've specified that you're just implementing the raw type `Comparable`, which has a method with a signature of:

```
int compareTo(Object)
```

The cleanest fix for this is to change the declaration of `PhoneNumber` to:

```
public abstract class PhoneNumber implements Comparable<PhoneNumber>
```

You *could* implement `compareTo(Object)` instead, but do you really want to be able to compare a phone number with *any* other object? It makes more sense (IMO) to just claim to be able to compare a phone number with other phone numbers.

Comment: I figured it was something obvious I was missing. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @user3010825 don't forget to accept Jon's answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 3):

You are implementing the raw version of `Comparable`, whose `compareTo` method takes an `Object`.

Implement the generic version of [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) instead:

```
public abstract class PhoneNumber implements Comparable<PhoneNumber>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
   public int compareTo(PhoneNumber other)
   {
      super.compareTo(other);
   }
```

to

```
   @Override
   public int compareTo(Object other)
   {
      return super.compareTo((PhoneNumber)other);
   }
```

Comment: Better to change `implements Comparable` to `implements Comparable<PhoneNumber>`

Answer (score 1):

That is because

```
Comparable.compareTo(Object o); {}
```

is not equal to

```
   public int compareTo(PhoneNumber other)
   {
      super.compareTo(other);
   }
```

Change

```
public abstract class PhoneNumber implements Comparable
```

to

```
public abstract class PhoneNumber implements Comparable<PhoneNumber>
```

and it will work the TypeSafe way you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

> does not override abstract method compareTo(Object) in Comparable

Your sub class doesn't have a `compareTo(Object)`  You could add such a method but the best solution is to change

```
public abstract class PhoneNumber implements Comparable<PhoneNumber> {
```

that way it expects a `compareTo(PhoneNumber)` which is what you have.